# Generating getters & setters in XCode

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode, getter

I am currently using xcode for some c++ development & I need to generate getters & setters.

The only way I know is generating getters & setters in Objective C style

something like this
- (string)name;
- (void)setName:(string)value;

I dont want this; I want c++ style generation with implementation & declaration for use in the header files.

Any idea...?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you're just looking for a way to reduce the hassle of writing getters/setters (i.e. property/synthesize statements) all the time right?

There's a free [macro](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/12/instance-variable-to-synthesized.html) you can use in XCode to even generate the @property and @synthesize statements automatically after highlighting a member variable that I find really helpful :)

If you're looking for a more robust tool, there's another paid tool called [Accessorizer](http://www.kevincallahan.org/software/accessorizer.html) that you might want to check out.

Answer (score 3):

Objective C != C++.

ObjectiveC gives you auto-implementation using the @property and @synthesize keywords (I am currently leaning ObjectiveC myself, just got a Mac!).  C++ has nothing like that, so you simply need to write the functions yourself.

Foo.h

```
inline int GetBar( ) { return b; }
inline void SetBar( int b ) { _b = b; }
```

or

Foo.h

```
int GetBar( );
void SetBar( int b );
```

Foo.cpp

```
#include "Foo.h"

int Foo::GetBar( ) { return _b; }
void Foo::SetBar( int b ) { _b = b; }
```

Comment: yes I know but my question is: like other IDEs can getters & setters be generated for c++ in XCode 
the only way I knew was generating objective c style getters & setters

Comment: XCode is not generating anything in ObjectiveC, that is a language feature, XCode is the IDE.

Comment: Actually, it's not a language feature. It's a compiler feature. The language has remained the same.

Comment: @ChristosSotiriou: No, `@property` and `@synthesize` are language features.

Comment: @EdS: I meant that 'property' and 'synthesize'  are language features (introduced with Objective  C 2.0, actually), but automatic variable synthesis (the ability to omit 'synthesize', and the automatic creation of _var variables) is a compiler feature, introduced with the compiler bundled with Xcode 4.4. However, if you disagree with that, I would really like to see some references, because I couldn't find any reference to support either argument (yours or mine), unfortunately.

Comment: @ChristosSotiriou: Ah, ok.  I think you may be right about that.

Answer (score -1):

something.h:

```
@interface something : NSObject
{
   NSString *_sName;  //local
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *sName;

@end
```

something.m :

```
#import "something.h"
@implementation something

@synthesize sName=_sName; //this does the set/get

-(id)init
{
...
self.sName = [[NSString alloc] init];
...
}

...


-(void)dealloc
{
   [self.sName release]; 
}
@end
```

Comment: The OP was asking for a C++ implementation.

Comment: This code also leaks - the [[NSString alloc] init] is never released.