# Generating getters/setters in C++ with XCode?

Tags: c++, xcode

I'm writing some C++ code for an iOS app, so I believe I have to use XCode to run/test the app. Is there a way to generate getters/setters and local or instance variables out of statements? Are there any alternatives?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1640848/generating-getters-setters-in-xcode

Comment: No alternatives even after 3+ years?

Comment: That's why I said "Possible".